# Different page radio buttons being pre-selected

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, radio-group

There are two pages; Section 1 on the first page and Section 2 on the second page.

The issue is that when Section 1 radio button is selected, i.e. `checked="checked"` and continue on to Page 2 / Section 2 the first radio button is preselected?! Notice the `checked="checked"`.

The names are the same because it is a dynamic questionnaire that is populated via RadioButtonFor via a view model.

Page 1 / Section 1 Radio button group:

```
Yes <input id="11" name="VIQuestions[1].Answer" type="radio" value="0">
No  <input id="12" name="VIQuestions[1].Answer" type="radio" value="1">
N/A <input id="13" name="VIQuestions[1].Answer" type="radio" value="2">
```

Page 2 / Section 2 Radio button group:

```
Yes <input id="71" name="VIQuestions[1].Answer" type="radio" value="0">
No  <input id="81" name="VIQuestions[1].Answer" type="radio" value="1">
N/A <input id="91" name="VIQuestions[1].Answer" type="radio" value="2">
```

I don't want to force the radio buttons to have nothing selected on page load because when the user submits the page and an error is found I want the browser to remember the users selections, so a blanket selection reset won't work.

I'm looking for a way so that when the first page is submitted, and no errors are found, then the second page loads; I then want to wipe any history of the selections made in page 1.

P.S. I think it's the name of the radio buttons, and their selections, being stored in the browser that is causing this, but it could be an MVC issue, I'm unsure.

**EDIT:** For completeness here is the MVC view code that outputs the radio buttons.

```
for (int j = 0; j < Model.VIQuestions.Count; j++)
{
    string questionId = Model.VIQuestions[j].VIQuestion_Id.ToString();

    <label><span>Yes</span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.VIQuestions[j].Answer, 1, new { id = questionId + 1 })</label>
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>No</span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.VIQuestions[j].Answer, 2, new { id = questionId + 2 })</label>
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>N\A</span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.VIQuestions[j].Answer, 3, new { id = questionId + 3 })</label>
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oops my bad, thought I already did it.

Comment: You need to show your relevant code. Are you using `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` to generate the radio buttons? (which use values from `ModelState` is they exist). What is the method you are posting to and what are you doing in that method - redirecting (correct) or returning the view (incorrect)? And you radio buttons do not even make sense - each is for a different property so you can select all of them (and cannot unselect any)

Comment: @StephenMuecke heya, I did explain that the radio buttons are output create using RadioButtonFor ... It is a redirect... I know it seems odd that they really do work as a group when all the names are different, but they do, you cannot select them all, they are a group, and on postback they are read using the viewmodel (because they are bound to it using RadioButtonFor)

Comment: They are a group in your edit - the original code at the top of you question is not a group and cannot work :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, sorry, I just realised my mistake (and corrected it, they all do have the same name), sorry!

Comment: Just as a side note, you might consider wrapping the radio button in a `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(...)<span<Yes</span></label>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks but doesn't the <label for=""> achieve the same?

Comment: Yes, it was just a suggestion (your `@Html.Raw()` looks a bit ugly)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thought I was missing something, however I agree, and have changed it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a form post to move between the pages of the questionnaire, then you will be hitting a feature where the model state is already pre-filled with the form values.  This is in case you need to show the form should validation fail etc.

If you are happy with the form values and want the user to carry on, then either do

```
this.ModelState.Clear();
```

before you redisplay the form, or use

```
this.RedirectToAction( ...
```

and have each question as a separate request.